# Eager load related models in Laravel's Revisionable history

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, revisionable

Using Laravel 5.4 and the [VentureCraft/revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) package.

I have 3 models: `User`, `Company` and `Order`.

The `Order` model implements the Revisionable trait:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Order extends Eloquent {
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

    // ...
}
```

The `User` model has a relationship with the `Company` model:

```
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company');
}
```

And I would like to eager load the company of a user from an order revision. Something like this

```
$order = Order::with('revisionHistory.user.company')->find(1);

foreach($order->revisionHistory as $revision) {
    $company = $revision->user->company;
}
```

I've tried overwriting various methods (e.g. `revisionHistory` and `identifiableName`) from the Revisionable trait without any luck.

Comment: not each revision history is for company_id field, you may filter out them first, and get company by id

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I'm not looking for changes in the `company_id` field. I'm trying to get the `Company` of the use who made the change in the `Order` model. All of the users has a company related.

Comment: understand! just answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible with the current version of the package.

The reason behind is that `userResponsible()` is not an actual relationship, it's just a function that returns an instance of the `User` model.

To allow eager loading, something like this would be needed:

```
public function userResponsible()
{
    if (class_exists($class = '\Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry')) {
        return $this->belongsTo(Config::get('sentry::users')['model'], 'user_id');
    } else if (class_exists($class = '\Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel')) {
        return $this->belongsTo(Config::get('sentinel::users')['model'], 'user_id');
    } else {
        return $this->belongsTo(Config::get('auth.model'), 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to eager load like this:

```
$order = Order::with('revisionHistory.userResponsible.company')->find(1);
```

You can view the original issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable/issues/104).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$company = $revision->userResponsible()->company` to get company of the `User` that change the `Order`.

Comment: That's a good start, I will try it out. But it doesn't seem to be eager loading.